# <ice:outputMedia>

Tags: jsf, icefaces

```
<ice:outputMedia player="flash" source="... /ICEfaces_Flash.swf"
                style="width:300px;height:250px;">
<f:param name="play" value="true"/>
<f:param name="menu" value="true"/>
</ice:outputMedia>
```

Above Code plays the flash file but doesnt show the controls !

Answer (score 0):

For Flash you get access to the controls via the context menu only.

Comment: wht i questioned is wht i get from Icefaces Docs ! CUd u jst Detail ur Answer ! Thank U !

Comment: Controls i meant was the --> Play , pause.. Buttons !

Comment: @Fayaz: I think you will get better response if you communicate in normal English in a more respectful manner. The above comments seem to be made by a 12-year old disrespectful kid who thinks that he's in midst of a MSN conversation with a "friend" or is sending a SMS. Sorry if I sound harsh, but that's just the way how your English is formulated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the context menu (aka right-click menu) will have the play, pause button.

`<param name="menu" value="true">` with a normal html page will do the trick, but it seems not to be working with icefaces (when using f:param) like u did.
Actually the [icefaces docs](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/docs/outputMediaDoc.html) says it should be done this way. Maybe it's a bug so i would recommend to add a thread on the [icefaces forum](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/forums/list.page).

Comment: Context Menu works Fine with Flash FIles in both Browserz (IE n Chrome) ! wen it comes to Other players , IE pops up de controls but Chrome doesnt (but playz de File ) !